# How to open 2 terminal windows side by side in IntelliJ's PyCharm?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I am trying to open multiple terminals in PyCharm. I am able to open multiple terminals but they are tabs. Is it possible to open them side by side? I looked from google but couldn't find anything.

I want like this:

```
+-------------+--------------+
|             |              |
|             |              |
|             |              |
|             |              |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Not like this:

```
+------+-------+
|      |       |
|      |       |
+------+-------+----------------+
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried `screen` or `tmux`?

Comment: PyCharm/IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support it yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141172.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you for that answer. I would have searched it way too long without your help. So for now I gotta find alternatives, something like Eli Korvigo suggested.